# TypeScript array sort by array off numbers

Tags: typescript

I Need to sort an array by ID. checkin another array of numbers

```
    var itens:[] = [{
    item:{id:1},item:{id:2},item:{id:3},item:{id:4}
    }]

var sort:[] = [1,3,2,4];
```

result:

```
var itens:[] = [{
    item:{id:1},item:{id:3},item:{id:2},item:{id:4}
    }]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting an array of objects by property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your items array is not really correct, that's an array of one item.

With that fixed, here is how you could sort:

```
const items = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}];
const sort = [1, 3, 2, 4];
const sorted = sort.map(val => items.find(item => item.id === val));
console.log(sorted);
```